# How to obfuscate android aar library with proguard?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, aar

I am trying to obfuscate my aar project code but the code is not getting obfuscated.I have set minifyEnabled true in my build.gradle.

Am i missing anything else let me know and how i solve this issue.

Thanks

My build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: show your build.gradle code

Comment: @Kunu I have updated my question please check.

Comment: Are you checking in a release build?

Comment: @Kunu Ya i am checking in the libraryname-release.aar file

Comment: please post the content of proguard-rules.pro file

Comment: @lelloman I have not written any rules in proguard-rules.pro.should i write any mandatory code in rules ? please let me know.

Comment: not that i know of, maybe something is already there? is it completely empty?

Comment: @lelloman Ya it is completely empty....